# How to find a solution knowing that gcd(512 , 200) = 8c ?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

i got this for homework , but i would like to know if i'm just supposed to substitute any value i want for c and , find a solution? Or am i to use c as an arbitrary value , and find a solution which would contain the variable c . Please note , i am not asking for the question to be one for me , but rather for help in doing it .

`Let c be any integer , Give a solution to 512x + 200y = 8c`

If it matters , in part a of the question we had to find a solution for  `512x + 200y = 8`

Answer (score 1):

You are to use $c$ as an arbitrary value and come up with a solution that always works, no matter what $c$ is. And problem part a matters a lot: If $x, y$ are chosen so that $512x + 200y = 8$, then multiplying with $c$ gives
$$
512(xc) + 200(yc) = 8c
$$
so using $x' = xc, y' = yc$ solves your problem.

Comment: My gosh... I've been up all night doing other subjects..thid is so obvious. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You said you already have a solution $(x,y)$ for $512x+200y=8$.

If you multiply this equation by $c$, you will find that

$$512xc+200yc=8c$$

So you can see that $(x',y') := (xc,yc)$ are the solutions to  $512x'+200y'=8c$.